# Laravel: middleware to determine which controller to use

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am building a site which loads all pages and content via javascript while also manipulating the browser address bar (giving the illusion of a normal, navigable site with each page at its own URL). As a fallback, and for the benefit of search engines, the pages must also be able to be loaded normally at their respective URLs.

To do this, I need to let Laravel know if the page data is being requested via an ajax call or normal HTTP request. This- I presume- would be a situation where I would use Middleware. I want to be able to process the pages using two different controllers; one for ajax, one for HTTP.

ie:

```
if (Request::ajax()){
    forward request to ajax page controller
}else {
    forward request to standard page controller
}
```

Is this possible to handle with middleware? All examples I can find seem to assume that the controller is already a given.

Comment: I think you need to use a `RouteServiceProvider` to achieve this. It is no way to use only middlewares

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

Comment: Middleware in general is triggered after identifying the route and apply the middle to it followed by the controller.

Comment: @MinaAbadir Your comment would imply that at the point of running the Middleware, the option is still open to choose which controller to pass to- that's what I was hoping/assuming. But it seems that Laravel can in fact only run Middleware after both route *and* controller have already been determined; it is impossible to switch controller within Middleware (?)

Comment: @Inigo my comment imply that, it's impossible. Because routes in Laravel require an action attached to that route. So once the route is identified, the action is selected. Middlewares are attached to the actions/controllers.

Comment: Yes, gotcha. The name *middleware* is somewhat misleading in this care because in essence it is not **route -> middleware -> controller**, but **route+contoller -> middleware**

Answer (score 1):

I use the `routes.php` file instead of middleware. I believe middleware is after the route has been determined.

```
if(Request::ajax() || Request::json()){
    Route::get('items', [
        'as' => 'api.posts.index' ,
        'uses' => 'Api\ItemsController@index'
    ]);
} else {
    Route::get('items', [
        'as' => 'posts.index' ,
        'uses' => 'ItemsController@index'
    ]);
}
```

I do it this way because I like to separate out the urls for json versus web.

```
Route::get('items', [
    'as' => 'posts.index' ,
    'uses' => 'ItemsController@index'
]);

/**
 * JSON API
 *
 */
Route::group([
         'prefix' => 'api/v1', 
         'as' => 'api.', 
         'namespace' => 'Api'
      ], function () {

    Route::get('items', [
        'as' => 'posts.index' ,
        'uses' => 'ItemsController@index'
    ]);

}
```

Either way your controllers would live here.

```
App/Http/Controllers/Api/ItemsController.php
App/Http/Controllers/ItemsController.php
```

### EDIT

I read the comment form GONG and the RouteServiceProvider would also work for this, but you would still have two distinct urls. You would have to manage another routes file, but whatever works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. OK, will go with just putting the if/else right there in the routes.php file then. I had hoped for something a bit more elegant but I guess this is the most straightforward way. As per the OP, my situation hinges on the URLs being identical so can't use the other suggestions.

Comment: Please note that the if statement should testing `Request::ajax`. So my code is as follows: `if(Request::ajax()){
    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'api.home' ,
        'uses' => 'API_Controller@index'
    ]);
} else {
    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'home' ,
        'uses' => 'Primary@index'
    ]);
}`

Comment: @Inigo Sorry for the typo I meant to have both ajax and json. I put that in my code because occasionally I would get a false negative if didn't have both of them. I updated my answer.